# ¿Relación entre tablas con campos alfanuméricos SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Materias12 (
Letra varchar(3) not null, 
Numero int identity(1,1) not null,
IdMateria as  (Letra +  right('00'  + cast(Numero as varchar(6)), 3)), 
NombreMateria varchar(100) not null,
NroDeProfesor varchar(200),)
```

Tengo `idmateria` que posee número y letras. Quiero que sea la clave primaria y relacionarlo con otro campo en otra tabla que sería su clave foránea. Quiero saber que tipo de datos sería la clave foránea, y si esa es clave foránea puede ser clave primaria en su tabla.

He tenido problemas en relacionar. Me dice que tipos de datos incorrectos... longitud diferente.

Comment: *he tenido problemas en relacionar*: Por favor, comparte lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, voy a asumir que cambiastes la columna `IdMateria` para que sea *persisted*. De lo contrario, no podrías definirla como clave primaria. Probablemente intentastes algo similar a esto:

```
create table Materias12 (
Letra varchar(3) not null, 
Numero int identity(1,1) not null,
IdMateria as  (Letra +  right('00'  + cast(Numero as varchar(6)), 3)) persisted primary key, 
NombreMateria varchar(100) not null,
NroDeProfesor varchar(200),)

create table OtraTabla (
  IdMateria varchar(10) not null primary key,
  col varchar(50) not null
  constraint OtraTablaFk foreign key (IdMateria) references Materias12 (IdMateria)    
)
```

Lo que causa el error siguiente al tratar de establecer la clave foránea:

> Column 'Materias12.IdMateria' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'OtraTabla.IdMateria' in foreign key 'OtraTablaFk'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

[**Demostración del error**](http://rextester.com/EKE81194).

Tal como dice el error, debes definir la columna de tu otra tabla para que no solo sea del mismo tipo (`varchar`), pero también de la misma longitud.  Y allí está la duda... ¿cómo puedes determinar la longitud de tu campo `IdMateria`?

En este caso, es posible deducirlo. Pero si quieres saberlo a ciencia cierta, puedes hacerlo ejecutando la consulta siguiente:

```
select data_type, character_maximum_length
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_name = 'Materias12'
   and column_name = 'IdMateria'
```

... lo que devuelve el resultado siguiente:

```
data_type    character_maximum_length
---------    ------------------------
 varchar               6
```

[**Demostración de la consulta**](http://rextester.com/ARFBP49074).

Este resultado tiene sentido, ya que `IdMateria` es el resultado de combinar `Letra`, que es un `varchar(3)`, y `right(..., 3)`, que también es de longitud 3, para un total de 6.

Con esta información en mano, ahora sabes que debes definir la columna para la clave foránea con el tipo `varchar(6)`, y esto te va a funcionar sin error:

```
create table Materias12 (
Letra varchar(3) not null, 
Numero int identity(1,1) not null,
IdMateria as  (Letra +  right('00'  + cast(Numero as varchar(6)), 3)) persisted primary key, 
NombreMateria varchar(100) not null,
NroDeProfesor varchar(200),)

create table OtraTabla (
  IdMateria varchar(6) not null primary key,
  col varchar(50) not null
  constraint OtraTablaFk foreign key (IdMateria) references Materias12 (IdMateria)    
)
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/OPTSD89043).

Otra opción es que definas de forma explícita la longitud de `IdMateria` para eliminar toda ambiguidad. Esto lo puedes hacer usando `cast(... as varchar(n))`. Por ejemplo, si deseas que `IdMateria` sea de tipo `varchar(10)`, puedes hacerlo así:

```
create table Materias12 (
Letra varchar(3) not null, 
Numero int identity(1,1) not null,
IdMateria as  cast(Letra +  right('00'  + cast(Numero as varchar(6)), 3) as varchar(10)) persisted primary key, 
NombreMateria varchar(100) not null,
NroDeProfesor varchar(200),)

create table OtraTabla (
  IdMateria varchar(10) not null primary key,
  col varchar(50) not null
  constraint OtraTablaFk foreign key (IdMateria) references Materias12 (IdMateria)    
)
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/NXJ16747).

> Quiero saber ... si esa es clave foránea puede ser clave primaria en su tabla

Como puedes ver en los ejemplos arriba, la respuesta es sí.